# Seeding with unique objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to seed my database with project with unique project name, however my seeder does not work as I intended.

Seed.rb

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do |n|
name = "project-#{n+1}"
category = "category-#{n+1}"
users.each { |user| user.projects.create!(name: name, category: category) }
end
```

If I remove  `validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true` it will create 50 projects for each user from 1 to 50, but then for the next user would do the same (count resets) and will create projects with titles from 1 to 50 which interferes with the validates rule.

Any ideas?

Comment: Contrary to what you stated in your question it isn't creating 50 projects for a user then moving on to the next user. You are evaluating the project and category name and then creating the project for each user (6 times) for each iteration. As Alex has stated you need to provide additional scope for the name as his answer suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get last `project_id` and initial counter with it. Too `user.id` as additional scope.

```
last_id = Project.last.try(:id) || 1
50.times do |n|
  name = "project-#{last_id+n}"
  category = "category-#{last_id+n}"
  users.each do |user| 
    user.projects.create!(name: ("#{name}-#{user.id}"), category: ("#{category}-#{user.id}")) 
  end
end
```

Too you can add `rand`, `Time.now.to_f.to_s`, `SecureRandom.hex(5)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex, however you forgot to define user_id as the code is not picking it up so I decided to go on and try 'user_id = User.id' but it is not correct, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Yes, my typo. Use `user.id` instead of `user_id`